# Copying data between 2 MySQL DBs - can a stored proc do this?

Tags: mysql, database-connection

We have two DBs on different servers - S1 is a remote server with a DB we use for login authentication, S2 has our application and app-database. When you login, we check the user against S1 and then create a user object in S2 using some S1 data.

Is this something a stored procedure in S2 can do - access a remote DB and select data from it - or would we be better having the application query S1 for data and then pass it to S2 to save?

Let's say I want to copy the `id` and `name` from DB1.users to `user_id` and `user_name` DB2.game_users, the ideal would be a stored procedure in DB2 which is simply passed `id` as a parameter... but how can it get permission to the remote DB?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the FEDERATED engine?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html

Comment: It seems a _really_ clunky approach, having to know the structure of the foreign table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pre append your database name to the elements in your query.

something like(assuming db1 and db2 are your databases):

```
SELECT db1.table1.id, db1.table1.country FROM db1, db2 ORDER BY db2.table2.cities
```

Comment: How do I handle login/authentication to a foreign DB from MySQL?